# JQuery Full Calendar with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, jstl

let me give answer am not using Json i dont no how to use i want 
    to dispaly my events in calender pls help me out"  [My db values is need to 
    display as per date and with total count in particular date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8dG.png) ",
     This is my jsp code

```
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card-box">


                                <div id="calendar"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end col -->
                    </div>  <!-- end row -->
```

**This is my full calender script am using in jsp page only :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
url: '/leavecalender';  /* might be this is wrong ? */
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                    );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    events:[data]
   });
    });
  </script>
```

**And this is my controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leavecalender")
public ModelAndView leave(ModelMap model) 
{
TeleCallRecordIdTO telecall = new TeleCallRecordIdTO();
List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> allcall = hrService.getallcalls();

model.addAttribute("allcall", allcall);

return new ModelAndView("HR/hr/leavesCalender","leavecalender",telecall);
}
```

**this is my service :**

```
public List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> getallcalls();
```

**this is my serviceImplementation :**

```
@Override
public List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> getallcalls() {
    return hrDao.getallcalls();
}
```

**This is my Dao :**

```
public List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> getallcalls();
```

**This is myDaoImplementation :**

```
@Override
public List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> getallcalls() {

List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    String s = "SELECT DATE(call_date) AS 'Date', COUNT(1) AS 'TotalCalls' 
     FROM tele_call_record GROUP BY DATE(call_date)";
    Connection connection=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(s);
    ResultSet rs= preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        TeleCallRecordIdTO tel=new TeleCallRecordIdTO();
        tel.setCallDate(rs.getString("Date"));
        /*tel.setExtensionNo(rs.getString("extension_no"));
        tel.setPhoneNo(rs.getString("phone_no"));*/
        tel.setSrNo(rs.getInt("TotalCalls"));
        list.add(tel);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return list;
}
```

Comment: what you want to do with your result data from database?

Comment: i have data in my database i have to display that data based on date in calendar ,else refer my snapshop for above second line link

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem you need to try this

**replace**

```
events:[data]
```

**with**

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/leavecalender',
        //data: {
            // data if you are passing
        //},
        success: function(data) {
            var events = [];
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                events.push({
                    title: data[index].srNo,
                    start: data[index].callDate,
                    //end:   data.end
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log( textStatus +" - "+ errorThrown );
        }
    });
}
```

**Change your controller method also:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leavecalender", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<TeleCallRecordIdTO> leave() {
    return hrService.getallcalls();;
}
```

Comment: events:[data] -> what i have to pass data?

Comment: with events:[data] just calendar is displaying not my data , with events:[data] nothing is showing

Comment: pls help me out today i need to complete this tasks

Comment: plese check what I have ask to do ? try to replace `events:[data]` with my answer

Comment: i replaced events:[data] to your answer but its not displaying my data,just display calendar

Comment: can you show `network tab` response of your browser ?

Comment: I don't use team viewer or skype ?

Comment: ok fine ..in network tag i am getting this type error: error - Not Found

Comment: can u tell me what to pass here   data: {
            
                // data if you are passing
            },

Comment: you are not passing data so remove this ?

Comment: Please  check I hava commented `data: { // data if you are passing },`

Comment: now check ajax updated url `url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/leavecalender',`   try with this

Comment: change your controller method mapping to `/leavecalender` as shown in answer

Comment: i changed controller might be i am getting error in passing data ..am not passing anything ,

Comment: var events = [];
                /* $.each(data, function(index) {
                    events.push({
                        title: data[index].srNo,
                        start: data[index].callDate,
                        //end:   data.end
                    });

Comment: give ur mail id i will share u..here not looking proper code after edit and save

Comment: i have rise new question?